# Is it possible to unwrap genus-0 mesh so each vert has one and only unique uv?

Tags: uv

To unwrap a genus-0 mesh such as a sphere, I can make a full sphere from an unwrapped half sphere applied with mirror modifier. **the amount of uvs equal the amount of vertices.**  But the two verts selected in image below have **two different uvs with the same value**.(by checking in the exported .obj)

Or I can make a seam then 'Unwrap'. This way the **number of uvs is larger than the amount of vertices**. Each uv coord is unique, no repeated values.

I wonder how to unwrap a genus-0 mesh so each vert has **one and only unique uv**? Unique means there're no repeated uv coord values, it's not unique if the ith `vt` and jth `vt` have the same coord values.

Comment: How did you know that the `v 1 2 3` represent a uv coord? I check the obj definition which indicate that `v` stand-for vertices coord and `vt` stand for uv values.

Comment: And I think it is totally possible to unwrap using only one uv per vertices (depend on how the data is interpreted). You can try project from view, which always give you a merged uv coord. And after export to `obj` file, the `vt` amount should meet the `v` numbers.

Comment: Also keep an eye on `f`. eg. A cube face:`f 8/5/6 4/13/6 2/14/6 6/7/6`. the element indicate which `vt` values to use in a face and vertices. So it doesn't to store duplicated data.

Comment: @Hikariztw Woops, I got the wrong screenshot. Let me update it

Comment: @Hikariztw Project from view will give me one uv per vert, but the half the vertices will share the same uv coord values with the other half. i.e. the uvs for (-1.5, 1,5, 3.0) and (1.5, 1,5, 3.0) are both (0.88, 0.30). What I'm looking for is that each vertex has a unique uv coord

Comment: @batFINGER It doesn't matter which projection Im using, my question was to make each vertex one and only unique uv with no repeated uv coords.  It's possible theoretically and in practice to merge the UV coords of boundary vertex . For example, for each boundary vertex, I can manually move the uvs to the same uv space, then remove the duplicated uv coords manually in text editor. But this is the most time consuming way.

Comment: @batFINGER I was playing around with this on a sphere and found one ok solution for the sphere, only one vert overlapping. You can check the updated question

Comment: Could  I enquire why you want to do this?

Comment: @batFINGER I want the uv to represent vertices too, and the texture of the verts on the back can be ignored. I guess I can try 'project from view' again and move the verts from the mirrored side slightly so each vert has a unique uv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ≫ I want the uv to represent vertices too, so each vert has a unique uv.

**If the word "represent" is to identify which vertex is it, then it is doable.**

A cube is almost the same thing to a UV sphere(g-0). You can project from view to make all uv shared by all edges and faces connect to it.

[image]

So we get 6 uv values only? **No**.

Actually, we still have 24 uv values inside Blender data. Those connected and shared vertices uv move together in Blender by default. You can even move the individual uv by adjust the selection option.

[image]

An uv map is depend on the topology of face. So there should be the same amount of uv tuples to represent a texture coordinate. In a cube, 4 for a face, and 6 face: 4×6=24 uv tuples. You can share the uv values, but you can't ignore that the uv query times should still be 24 to mapping the texture space.

Comment: Technically 100% right. I just thought he does not like seams and expressed his desire to get rid of them in a complex way. But if its the uniqueness alone is whats important, than this works perfectly ;)

Comment: Yes, project from view indeed seems to be a solution. You actually get 8 uvs when export it into .obj, I do not know where 24 come from tho.Thanks

Comment: @JuneWang From how blender treat those data in python. When export to obj, those connect and shared vertices were combined automatically to single data record.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Unwrap. Meaning peeling the surface off of a solid and laying it out flat on the ground.

If your requirement is that there are no duplicated texture coordinates at all, it would mean that you are trying to peel an orange without cutting its skin. Even if you manage to "beam off" the skin in one piece you end up with a hollow shell that you cannot lay out flat on the ground without the front and back sharing the same area.

And the moment you cut it you get seams and therefore more uvs than vertices. if you merge them again later you once more end up in the situation described above.

This is true for all solids, not just genus-0 ones like a sphere.

Comment: Solids have no holes/knots are also genus-0. Okay, looks like this overlapping situation is inevitable. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible to have each _vertex_ with a unique UV, but not every interpolated surface point.

Comment: @RobinBetts What's the difference?

Comment: @June e.g.  trivially, you could project from view the front half of a sphere, move its UVs out of the way, and then project the back half. No two _verts_ would have the same UV, but the faces stretched between them would overlap.